# How to use a variable from another class in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ios7

basically the problem I have is this:

helloworldlayer in class I have a variable that I want to show in another class.

**in classe helloworldlayer.h**

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer <GKAchievementViewControllerDelegate, GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate>
{
    int _probar;
}

@property (nonatomic,readwrite)int probar;
```

**and the helloworldlayer.m**

```
@synthesize probar=_probar;
```

**for use in other classe I do this**

```
HelloWorldLayer *myobject = [[HelloWorldLayer alloc] init];
distan = myobject.probar;
```

everything works perfect if the Variable _probar give a value
in the init helloworldlayer.m example:

```
_probar = 20;
```

but if I put a variable constant while changing does not work. for example

```
- (void)updateDistancia:(ccTime)dt
{
   otra =+1; 
   _probar = otra;
}
```

in the other class tells me that equals zero, and i do not understand why, if someone tells me that this will be happening much appreciate or you have another solution.

Comment: How have you defined otra?

Comment: in what class is the updateDistancia method ?

Comment: otra I have defined as int in helloworldlayer.h and updatedistancia is  in the class hellowordlayer.m

Comment: did you confirm that updateDistancia is actually called ?

Comment: wrong answer : that would be the idea that it gets called. actually verify means 1) put an NSLog or 2) place a breakpoint, and eyeball that the call happens. Anyways, i think that if you dont 'add' helloWorldLayer as a child of a running node, your method will never be called (myObject up there in your code).

Answer (score 0):

I think removing `int _probar;` will solve the issue.

`@property (nonatomic,readwrite)int probar;` will automatically be backed by a iVar named _probar and have getter and setter generated. So the `@synthesize probar=_probar;` is not needed.

`@synthesize probar=someName;` is only telling the compiler to back the property with a iVar named someName instead of the default name. In your case you already have an iVar with the default name so the property and iVar is pointing at different ints.

Comment: I would add that he should be using this.probar to set and read the value, never directly setting the internal variable.  As you say you can also remove the definition of the variable from the class.

Comment: Yes self.probar is the best practice however not in init methods. But it's just a best practice and self.probar, [self probar] and _probar should give the same result if default getters and setters are used.

Comment: The are not all the same if anything else is using KVC to monitor changes in the object, or if the property is atomic.  Even in init you should ALWAYS use the accessors because you never quite know when you may want to change the property definition or add other behavior around setting.